# How can I block certain website on ASA 5520 Firewall?

Tags: firewall

Please help me to solve the problem.  I have ASA 5520 series Firewall & I want to block high bandwidth consumption website to get better performance for my network like:- 
•   I want to block all pornography websites. 
•   Some websites according to the schedule. 
•   Block all chat but allow Skype.
Thanks with kind regard.

Comment: So here's the thing: If viewing pornography on your work network is causing so much bandwidth consumption that it affects the rest of your network, then you have a HR problem, not a technical problem.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: I find content type quotas more effective to pornography problems, anyway: you can see it on their faces after a page gets replaced by an automated message "from" ICT department that they have reached their daily content type limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Blocking Sites**

Blocking sites is not something you would want to handle with a firewall.

Don't get me wrong, you can but it's a pain in the butt to maintain it, because that's not what firewalls are meant to do you'll have to manually update your configuration all the time. 
The problem is there are INCREDIBLE amounts of porn and other traffic intensive sites, and regex have proven to be bad for this task over the last two decades.

So in short: possible but impractical.

Officially, Cisco can do this with regex and manual entries, here's the guide:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100535-asa-8x-regex-config.html

The better way to do it is to do it with a transparent proxy such as Squid, which supports blacklists in text format. Also there are many providers of maintained blacklists online, which are mostly sorted into categories of blacklists (e.g. "porn", "social media", etc.).

Some examples:

- http://dsi.ut-capitole.fr/blacklists/index_en.php (compeltely free)
- https://www.squidblacklist.org/downloads.html (partially free)

Here's a guide on how to use blacklists in squid:
http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/03/20/squid-proxy-server-to-block-websites-listed-in-file/

General installation guides can be found all over the net, one good for transparent proxy configuration for squid on CentOS/RHEL 7 is here:
http://broexperts.com/how-to-configure-squid-3-x-as-transparent-proxy-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

This of course requires a lot of work, but it's more efficient in the long run.

**easy porn block method not under your control**

If you just want to block adult content, use openDNS as DNS server (after your DNS of course):
https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/#family

Downside: Not under your control, only porn block, intransparent for you.

**Blocking messengers**

That you can do with a firewall and/or with a proxy, depends on the messenger, some use centralized systems, some are decentralized, some use fixed ports, some not. It's impossible to write a general guide to "block all messengers but Skype", because not only are there countless numbers of them, but also they are configurable, (aka which ports they use etc.) so you basically need packet inspection to block certain protocols (such as XMPP).

Answer (score 1):

While you can do many of things with Cisco ASA 5520, they are not bundled to the hardware, and you are not giving any specifications about your licensing or modules. You might need additional licenses to be able to enable all the *security contexts* needed, and it might be hard to get such as ASA 5520 [has been](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5500-series-next-generation-firewalls/eol_C51-727279.html) *End of Sale* since Sep 2013 and *End of New Service Attachment* since Sep 2014. As all support will end on Sep 2018, you shouldn't plan any new features now.

Also, you have already mentioned three different use cases which all need different approach:

- *Block all pornography websites.* You need web content filtering by content type. This means someone has to keep list of web sites and their content. That's not a device but a service. It can be performed using a device, but the device needs to utilize such service.

  ASA 5520 *URL Filtering* feature supports only static black/white lists, and  support for Websense and Smartfilter; both external commercial services.
- *Some websites according to the schedule.* Possible with URL filtering. Easy for HTTP, but on HTTPS you can only block connection based on DNS resolving to the IP, or decrypt the traffic.
- *Block all chat but allow Skype.* This could mean content type filtering too, but more likely also blocking protocols based on ports. For the latter, your ASA 5520 is a correct tool, but many communication systems nowadays utilizes alternative methods falling to HTTPS port `443`.

Your main concern being bandwidth consumption, content filtering might not be the only approach. ASA 5520 also has [QoS features](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/asa-qos/ta-p/3115852) like *traffic policing*, *traffic shaping* and *priority queuing*. While handling the current situation with these, map your requisites in order to get a suitable firewall / IDS / IPS / UTM solution based on your needs, since you need to replace the EOL equipment soon.